# How can you schedule messages on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, messages, text, macos

I am looking for an app that lets me schedule messages to have them sent at a specific time? I do not mind paying as I know this is not something offered for free, but the ones I have tried so far (Delayed and Scheduled) have not been working at all.

I am looking for something that does more then just send a reminder to send the message.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This is a common request and you can see (from Search) that it's been asked a few times over the years.  This can't be done with native Apple devices due to security concerns.  You would need to use a 3rd-party service but, as you've found, they're not very good.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Due to restrictions placed on third-party apps by Apple, this is not possible. What many apps available on the App Store can do is send you a notification at the scheduled date/time. The intended message still has to be sent manually. There are few tweaks available for Jailbroken devices if you are wiling to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no native option to have the message sent at a scheduled time, I have been using an app Called [Auto Sender](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sms-auto-sender/id1375015129?mt=8) for the past month or so, and have been finding it works very well.

How it works is by storing the message on their server, and then sending the message from a generated number at the scheduled time. While it is not possible to have the message automatically sent from your number due to restrictions placed by apple, this method works well if you don't mind it coming from a different number. It also automatically includes your number at the end of the message, so the recipient knows who sent it. It also offers a signature that will appear at the end of the message, which allows you to enter your name in if you would like.

For the past month or so all my messages have been sent exactly on time! While there is a cost associated with each message due to them storing it on their servers, I find it cheaper then any other iOS alternative.

Comment: Hm okay, I will test it out and report back on how well it is working! Thanks

Comment: So I have tried the Auto Sender and it has been working well so far! I sent a few different test messages and they were all delivered exactly on schedule... I will continue using it for now but will update this post if I have any issues with it in the future.